# How to configure a workflow in EZPublish?

Tags: php, workflow, ezpublish

I'm working on a project that request clearing caches after every content publication or update. 
The thing is that normally EZpublish do it by itself, but in my case it is not enought, so what I was trying to do is to make a workflow event to do this.

I've consulted this [tutorial](http://share.ez.no/learn/ez-publish/creating-a-simple-custom-workflow-event) but I can't call the execute function that I create.

Is anyone have an idea how to create a workflow event that is called after content publication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for this [tutoriel1](http://share.ez.no/learn/ez-publish/creating-a-simple-custom-workflow-event)  and this [tutoriel2](http://share.ez.no/blogs/thiago-campos-viana/tip-the-minimum-workflow-event-extension) on how to create a workflow.
And when creating a new event form the administration interface look for Type you have juste created and not the predifined event types ( multiplexer , approuve .... )
Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an extension, I will call it "yourextension", with a new event type, I will call it "publishevent".

Note: if you are using eZ Publish before version 5.0 you have to leave out "ezpublish_legacy/" in the paths

ezpublish_legacy/extension/yourextension/eventtypes/event/publishevent/publisheventtype.php:

```
<?php

/**
 * Class PublishEventType
 */
class PublishEventType extends eZWorkflowEventType
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->eZWorkflowEventType( 'publishevent', 'description of what you are doing' );
        $this->setTriggerTypes( array(
            'content' => array(
                'publish' => array( 'after' ),
            )
        ) );
    }

    /**
     * This is where your code goes
     *
     * @param eZWorkflowProcess $process
     * @param eZWorkflowEvent $event
     * @return int
     */
    function execute( $process, $event )
    {
        $parameters = $process->attribute( 'parameter_list' );

        if ( isset( $parameters['object_id'] ) && isset( $parameters['version'] ) )
        {
            $objectId = (int) $parameters['object_id'];
            $version = (int) $parameters['version'];

            // your code goes here
        }

        return eZWorkflowType::STATUS_ACCEPTED;
    }
}

eZWorkflowEventType::registerEventType( 'publishevent', 'PublishEventType' );
```

ezpublish_legacy/extension/yourextension/settings/workflow.ini.append.php:

```
<?php /*

[EventSettings]
ExtensionDirectories[]=yourextension
AvailableEventTypes[]=event_publishevent

*/
```

Don't forget to active your new extension.

ezpublish_legacy/settings/override/site.ini.append.php:

```
[ExtensionSettings]
ActiveExtensions[]=yourextension
```

Does this help you?

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have done all this but yet i can't find a texte that I write in execute function using eZLog::write.

Comment: Which text are you looking for @Mahmoud?

Comment: when I create my workflow, I add this line `( eZLog::write("test") )` in my execute function, the probleme is that I never find the word "test" im my "common.log" file, wich means the execute function is never called.
And that is because I used the Type Multiplexer for my Event workflow ( thank's to @ADA15 I noticed that )

Answer (score 0):

As a side note: do you know that you can tweak which content's caches get expired upon publication using the so called 'smart view cache'? There is an ini file for that: viewcache.ini. It is a bit cryptic, but fairly well documented on the ez4 docs online.
Maybe you can get away with using this functionality and no custom workflows?

Side note 2: you can look up the community extension ezworkflowcollection for a lot of useful workflow events you can use for different things (even though cache clearing is not one of those)